# Centering a button in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Using gravity on LinearLayout centers the button correctly:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But using layout_gravity=center on the Button only centers the button horizontally and not vertically, why?

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the `layout_gravity` can make button center in LinearLayout.
Helpful article: [LinearLayout gravity and layout_gravity explained](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html)
Check the simple code below. It will give you a button in **center horizontal** of `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button Center Hozizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Button Center Vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0ff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Button Center Vertical/ Horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Image Screenshot]

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried this - it's the same issue, it only centers the button horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: do you tried it in another layout. i mean you create new layout and use this code. I have tested it and it work

Comment: I tried your exact code (and nothing else) and the preview shows it centering horizontally but not vertically. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: @Boon: Could you please show your screen of this issue? 1 image = 100 words ^^

Comment: @MrNeo Screen attached.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Thanks. I want the button to center both horizontally and vertically. Your example shows it can only do it on one axis, which is what I got.

Comment: @Boon I think it is the way linearlayout should work. you see linearlayout just organize item by one orientation (vertical or horiziontal) not organize both orientation in one linearlayout. 
If you want button in both  horizontal and vertical, i'm strong suggest `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Thanks - I thought from reading the doc that layout_gravity is the opposite of gravity, where the former applies with respect to its parent and another applies to all its subviews. In this case it's clearly not.

Comment: @Boon: I found [this article](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.com/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) explain quite clearly about `layout_gravity`. As Linh said, `linearlayout` only organize item by one orientation, so with each orientation, `layout_gravity` has different value.

Comment: @MrNeo Thanks. If LinearLayout can only work in one direction, why would using gravity on it work in two directions?

Comment: @Boon  `layout_gravity` will work in side `LinearLayout` but it will not work with another layout like `RelativeLayout`. However with `gravity` you can use it with any component (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, Button, TextViewm ...). As far as I know now, I think it is the different

Comment: @MrNeo Thanks for the article, it's helpful.

Comment: I never use `gravity` in LinearLayout before. However I think if you use gravity in LinearLayout, it will really hard to add some compent to your LinearLayout. If your LinearLayout have 1 item it will be ok but think about your linearlayout have 2 3 item.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Thanks for the screenshot and updated code.

Comment: @Boon you also help me to understand clearly the new things. Thanks a lot. Also thanks MrNeo for providing this helpful article

Comment: In my opinion, Google should have explaination about this. Because on Android developer site, they also say that `layout_gravity` could align items in X axis and Y axis, same as `gravity` explaination. LOL. Thanks all, this is new for me ^^.

Answer (score 0):

`gravity` is defined in `ViewGroup` (only `ViewGroup` and its subclass have this attribute). And `layout_gravity` is defined in `View`.

`layout_gravity` changes the view's gravity, so far so good. But if you apply `gravity` to a `ViewGroup`, such as a `LinearLayout`, the views *inside* the view group changes gravity.

**Which means, setting `gravity` of a `ViewGroup` is the same as setting `layout_gravity` to all its views!**

The sentence in bold certainly answers your question.

Comment: I read this and I don't understand why layout_gravity only centers my button horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: @Boon I guess it's because your `LinearLayout` is vertical.

Comment: I tried changing LinearLayout to horizontal or removing it, now it only centers it vertically and not horizontally.

Comment: Yeah. See? layout_gravity depends on the parent layout's orientation! So if you want it right in the center, use gravity instead. @Boon

Comment: I am trying to understand why I am getting this behavior. Parent is set to vertical at all times, why would gravity work and not layout_gravity? Also, what should be set for parent for layout_gravity to work?

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/b1"
         android:text="COLOR"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```